# Sieve of Sundaram (for finding prime numbers)

Tags: code-golf, math, number, primes

## The Challenge

Implement [the Sundaram sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram) for finding prime numbers below `n`. Take an input integer, `n`, and output the prime numbers below `n`. You can assume that `n` will always be less than or equal to one million.

---

## Sieve

1. Start with a list of the integers from `1` to `n`.
2. Remove all numbers that are in the form `i + j + 2ij` where:

   - `i` and `j` are less than `n`. `j` is always greater than or equal to `i`, which is greater than or equal to `1`.
     [image]
   - `i + j + 2ij` is less than or equal to `n`
     [image]
3. Multiply the remaining numbers by `2`, and add `1`.

This will yield all the prime numbers (except `2`, which should be included in your output) less than `2n + 2`.

---

Here is an animation of the sieve being used to find primes below `202`.

[image]

---

## Output

Your output should be every prime integer `≤ n` (in ascending order) followed by a newline:

```
2
3
5
```

Where `n` is `5`.

---

## Examples

```
> 10
2
3
5
7

> 30
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
```

Inputs are denoted by `>`.

Comment: Your example with `n=30` is missing 29 in the output.

Comment: A trouble with challenges that ask to use a specific method is that it's not clear what modifications one can make. For example, your description checks only `(i,j)` with `i<=j`, but the result doesn't change if we ignore this requirement. Can we do so to save bytes?

Comment: I never said that you had to check if `i <= j`. It's just part of how the sieve works. So yes, you can leave out the `i <= j` in your code. @xnor

Comment: How much leeway do we have here? The sieve is equivalent to selecting all odd numbers (because the results are of the form `2n+1`) which are not of the form `2(i + j  + 2ij)+1` - can we test this property directly on the potential primes or does our code *have* to do the times 2 plus 1 at some point?

Comment: You must multiply the filtered results by two and add one. @MartinBüttner

Comment: Nice challenge! I haven't heard of this method before. I got confused at "except two", as I thought it meant there were two primes not included. Perhaps you should just change it to "except `2`" or something similar. Also, I believe you forgot the `5` in the first example (where `n` is `5`), unless this was intentional.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've also fixed the example. @ETHproductions

Comment: `i` must be >1, `j` must be >i, so the sieve starts with i=2,j=3 and the first eliminated number is `i + j + 2ij ->  2 + 3 + 2*2*3 = 17`.  How is the example eliminating 4,7,10,12,13,15...?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what `n` is in the whole thing. In the method description, it says that it will generate all primes up to `2 * n + 2`. But in the input/output description, it says that the input is `n`, and the output all primes up to `n`. So are we supposed to apply the method to generate all primes up to `2 * n + 2`, and then drop the ones larger than `n` for the output? Or should we calculate the `n` in the method description from the input `n`?

Comment: You should calculate and then drop the ones larger than `n`. @RetoKoradi

Comment: There's a difference between text and formula. In the text, it says "j is always greater than i, which is greater than 1". In the formula, it shows `>=` for both of these, not `>`.

Comment: I've fixed it. @RetoKoradi

Comment: I assume it is legit to take n >= 2 as granted (considering it doesnt make sense to look for primes smaller than 2) as all of the solutions dont consider that case?

Comment: Does the initial array have to start with 1, or can it start with 0 to simplify indexing? Do all of the calculations have to be done in that order, or can you pre-calculate the `2n + 2` values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pyth, 23 bytes

```
2j@JSQmhyd-Jm+sdy*Fd^J2
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=2j%40JSQmhyd-Jm%2Bsdy%2aFd%5EJ2&input=30&debug=0)

Really just implements the algorithm as given.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>93</s> 90 bytes

```
import Data.List
g n=unlines[show$2*x+1|r<-[[1..n]],x<-2:(r\\[i+j+2*i*j|j<-r,i<-r]),2*x<n]
```

How it works: `[i+j+2*i*j|j<-r,i<-r]` are all `i+j+2ij` which are removed (`\\`) from `[1..n]`. Scale to `2x+1` and turn them into a string (`show`). Join with NL (`unlines`).

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <s>115 124 122 115</s> 114 bytes

```
n=>{println(2);for{m<-1 to n;if !(for{j<-1 to n;i<-1 to j}yield i+j+2*i*j).contains(m);o=2*m+1;if o<=n}println(o)}
```

An anonymous function; takes n as an argument and prints the result to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>107</s> 105 bytes

Array comprehensions are awesome! But I wonder why JS has no range syntax (e.g. `[1..n]`)...

```
n=>{for(a=[i=1];i<n;a[i++]=i);for(i=0;i++<n;)for(j=0;j<n;a[i+j+++2*i*j]=0);return[for(i of a)if(i)i*2+1]}
```

This was tested successfully in Firefox 40. Breakdown:

```
n=>{
  for(a=[i=1];i<n;a[i++]=i); // fill a list with 1..n
  for(i=0;i++<n;)            // for each integer i in 0..n
    for(j=0;j<n;)            //   for each integer j in 0..n
      a[i+j+++2*i*j-1]=0;    //     set the corresponding item of the list to 0
  return[for(i of a)         // filter the list by:
          if(i)              //   item != 0 AND item != undefined
           i*2+1]            // and return each result * 2 + 1
}
```

Alternative, ES6-friendly solution (111 bytes):

```
n=>{for(a=[i=1];i<n;a[i++]=i);for(i=0;i++<n;)for(j=0;j<n;a[i+j+++2*i*j]=0);return a.filter(x=>x).map(x=>x*2+1)}
```

Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 98

```
n=1:input('');m=n;for p=m for i=1:p j=i:p;for k=i+j+2*i*j n(n==k)=[];end;end;end;disp(2*n'+1);
```

And in a readable form

```
n=1:input(''); %Ask for the input number (e.g. 100) and form a range
m=n; %Back up the range as we will be editing 'n', but need 'm' as a loop list
for p=m %For each number between 1 and n inclusive
    for i=1:p %'i' is all numbers greater than or equal to 1 up to p
        j=i:p; %'j' is all numbers greater than or equal to i up to p
        for k=i+j+2*i*j %Calculate the numbers to remove, and loop through them
            n(n==k)=[]; %Remove that value from the 'n' array
        end
    end
end
disp([2;2*n'+1]); %An display the list including the number 2 seperated by a new line.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java8 : <s>168</s> 165 bytes

```
N->{int[]A=new int[N*N];int i=1,j;N=N/2;for(;i<N;i++)for(j=i;j<N;)A[i+j+2*i*j++]=1;System.out.println(N>1?2:\"\");for(i=1;i<N;i++)if(A[i]<1)System.out.println(2*i+1);}
```

For more bigger number data type with wide range can be used. We do not need to iterate for whole `N` indexes `N/2` is sufficient.

To understand properly following is the equivalent method.

```
static void findPrimeSundar(int N){
    int[] A = new int[N*N];
    int i=1,j;
    N=N/2;
    for(;i<N;i++)
      for(j=i;j<N;)
        A[i+j+2*i*j++]=1;
    System.out.println(N>1?2:"");
    for(i=1;i<N;i++)
        if(A[i]<1)System.out.println(2*i+ 1);
}
```

Comment: `N>=2` -> `N>1`? `A[i]==0` -> `A[i]<1`?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Yes you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 35 bytes

```
2li:V,:)__2m*{_:+\:*2*+}%m2f*:)&+N*
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=2li%3AV%2C%3A)__2m*%7B_%3A%2B%5C%3A*2*%2B%7D%25m2f*%3A)%26%2BN*&input=30)

This seems somewhat lengthy relative to isaacg's Pyth solution, but it's... what I have.

Explanation:

```
2       Push a 2, will be part of final output.
li      Get input and convert to integer n.
:V      Save in variable V for later use.
,       Generate list [0 ... n-1].
:)      Increment list elements to get list [1 ... n].
__      Create two copies, one for sieve, and for clamping results.
2m*     Cartesian power, generating all i,k pairs.
{       Loop over all i,j pairs.
  _     Copy pair.
  :+    Calculate sum i + j.
  \     Swap copy of pair to top.
  :*    Calculate product i * j.
  2*    Multiply by 2, to get 2 * i * j.
  +     Add both values, to get i + j + 2 * i * j.
}%      End loop over all i,j pairs.
m       Sieve operation, remove the calculated values from the list of all values.
2f*     Multiply the remaining values by 2...
:)      ... and add 1 to the. We now have the list of all primes up to 2 * n + 2.
&       Intersect with [1 ... n] list, because output is only values <= n.
+       Concatenate with the 2 we pushed at the start.
N*      Join with newlines.
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 96 bytes

If I strictly follow the description the shortest I managed to get is 96 bytes.

```perl6
->\n {$_=@=1..n;for 1..n {for $^i..n {.[$i+$^j+2*$i*$j-1]=0}};2,|.[0..n].map(* *2+1).grep(3..n)}
```

```perl6
->\n {
  $_=@=1..n; # initialize array
  for 1..n { # $i
    for $^i..n { # $j
      .[$i+$^j+2*$i*$j-1]=0 # remove value
    }
  };
  2,|.[0..n].map(* *2+1).grep(3..n)
}
```

---

If I could do the `2n + 1` on initialization of the array, pre-inserting `2`, and limiting that to only the values less than or equal to `n`; it can be reduced to 84 bytes.

```perl6
->\n {$_=@=2,{++$*2+1}...^*>n;for 1..n {for $^i..n {.[$i+$^j+2*$i*$j]=$}};.grep(?*)}
```

If I also ignore that `j` is supposed to be at least `i`, I can reduce it to 82 bytes.

```perl6
->\n {$_=@=2,{++$*2+1}...^*>n;for 1..n X 1..n ->(\i,\j){.[i+j+2*i*j]=$};.grep(?*)}
```

---

Example usage:

```perl6
my $code = ->\n {...} # insert one of the lambdas from above

say $code(30).join(',');
# 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29

my &code = $code;
say code 11;
# (2 3 5 7 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 126 Bytes

```
$r=range(1,$n=$argn/2-1);for(;++$i**2<=$n;)for($j=$i;$n>=$d=$j+$i+2*$i*$j++;)unset($r[$d-1]);foreach($r as$v)echo 1+2*$v."\n";
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/909649282e811fabbb67640541d829efe447bbb4)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 65 bytes

```julia
n->[2;(p=setdiff(1:n,[i+j+2i*j for i=1:n for j=i:n])*2+1)[p.<=n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hck9DsIwDEDhPafwaDcBNUEwFMxFogxIrSVHlYlKOX/42Z6@V9@rPi5dgKHb4Z7TFRu/ln1WEYyThay@@qRDBXluoPy1f1XWyQoNyUfK7XhjK6X/hoEa4DlAHAOcRnIAbVPbV0NBI3KLza5/AA)

Not a great challenge in terms of golfing, but I just had to do it for the name. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 24 bytes

```
¶↑≤¹:2m+1mDṠ-om§+oDΠΣπ2ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9odXNr///CtuKGkeKJpMK5OjJtKzFtROG5oC1vbcKnK29EzqDOo8@AMuG4o////zMw)

Ok, I'm not sure why increment `→` isn't working properly here. Once that works, this will be 23 (tied with Pyth).